# 403 RBAC: access denied with Istio AuthorizationPolicy and JWT

Tags: jwt, istio, istio-gateway

I am receiving 403 RBAC access denied when trying to use Istio AuthorizationPolicy with JWT. I followed this [doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/security-issues/) to verify the configuration, everything looks to be correct.

**AuthorizationPolicy**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: dev
spec:
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        requestPrincipals:
        - mlp/73-DEV-1692600995774
    to:
    - operation:
        methods:
        - POST
        paths:
        - /generate*
  - to:
    - operation:
        methods:
        - GET
        paths:
        - /metrics
        - /health
        - /info
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
```

**JWT Payload**

```
{
  "sub": "73-DEV-1692600995774",
  "aud": "73-DEV",
  "nbf": 1692662400,
  "iss": "mlp",
  "exp": 1724284799,
  "iat": 1692724523,
  "jti": "1b893ac3-d49d-4e78-ab4f-b97a1a6255f2"
}
```

**Gateway**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - my-app.dev.company.com
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: my-app
      mode: SIMPLE
```

**Virtual Service**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: dev
spec:
  gateways:
  - my-app
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /test/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-app
        port:
          number: 8080
```

**App Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:      
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app
  namespace: dev
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: my-app
  type: ClusterIP
```

So the GET calls work fine, only the POST call (`https://my-app.dev.company.com/test/generate`) with valid JWT token (with above mentioned payload) in the Authorization header fails with 403 RBAC: access denied error.

Even giving `*` in requestPrincipals does not help. I am totally lost here, any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Looking into istio-proxy logs for the POST request I see this.

```
rbac_access_denied_matched_policy[none]
```

Looks like rule[0] is not getting matched and thus the RBAC error but do not know why the first rule is not getting matched.

Comment: Do you have the `RequestAuthentication` resource and the `forwardOriginalToken` set to true?

Comment: @peterj Yes, I do have `RequestAuthentication` with `forwardOriginalToken` set to true. Let me add that to the post.

Comment: @peterj As I was going to add the `RequestAuthentication`, I realized that I have bad match selector set for which was the cause of 403. Thank you.